# Bootstrap DatePicker setDate method not updating calendar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm setting the value of a bootstrap datepicker by making use of the `setValue` method provided.

For example

```
tripToDatePicker.setValue(tripFromDatePicker.date);
```

But for some reason the calendar is not updated

[image]

Answer (score 7):

**Edit:**

http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/ is not much documented, you should try http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/.

anyway the code below will work for you

```
$("#dp1").datepicker("update", "02-16-2012");
```

or

```
$("#dp1").datepicker("setValue", "02-17-2012");
```

*where "#dpi" is the id of the text field on whcih datepicker is used.*

Comment: Some more explaination would be appropriate.

Comment: This is giving me a 'Object doesn't support property or method setDate' exception

Comment: @user65439 give me a link to download the plugin you are using.

Comment: http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter

Comment: I tried both these method, but still no luck, pretty sure it is a bug within their javascript, might be a good idea to try the latest version

Answer (score 7):

'setValue' is replaced by 'setDate'.

Using a string as input for setDate can be tricky. It has to match with the dateformat, else you can get unexpected results. It is more safe to create a 'new Date(y,m,d)' from your input, e.g. new Date(2015,3,10) for '10 Apr 2015'. This will always work.

When using a date representation in seconds, e.g. 1428659901, then use 'new Date(value*1000)'. Note that datepicker will eat any value here, but only show the selected date in the calendar if hours, minutes and seconds are equal to 0. Took me a while to figure that out....

Comment: "Note that datepicker… only show[s] the selected date in the calendar if hours, minutes and seconds are equal to 0" +1 for this. I couldn't figure out why it wasn't updating for hours. Seems like a bug on their part

Comment: Your hint about the time solved it for me. If I remove it with `myDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);` everything works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After trying many things, I ended up using "update" method. The `$("#dp1").datepicker("update", "02-02-2012")` or `$("#dp1").datepicker("update", "02/02/2012")` works for me. Surprisingly no document about this method at author website. Thanks.